# Enable a disabled SonarLint rules in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sonarlint, android-studio-plugin

I accidentally disable one of SonarLint plugin rules in Android Studio and I tried to open its settings but cannot see where I can re-enable it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio, go to **`Settings > Tools > Sonarlint > Rules`**.

You should see disabled rules are colored.

You can restore all rules by `Restore Defaults` or just enable the rules one by one.

Hope it helps.